# No value for key bound to thread (Grails)

Tags: hibernate, grails, service

i'm developing a web application with Grails. My environment specs are:

- Groovy Grails Tool Suite (GGTS) 3.6.0.M1-e4.4-win32-x86_64
- Hibernate 4.3.5.3
- Groovy 2.3
- Grails 2.4.0
- Windows 8.1 Pro N

I start the application, and on the grails start page i choose this controller:

```
class UploadController {

    def index() { }

    def upload() {
    forward(controller: "parser", action: "takeUploadedFiles")
    }
}
```

With just this controller there would not happen anything. The corresponding .gsp is this upload form. I use it to upload multiple files at once.

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<meta name="layout" content="main"/>
<title>Inhalte einlesen</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="body">
    <g:uploadForm controller="upload" action="upload" autocomplete="off"> 
    <label for="files">Bitte alle HTML-Dateien einer Kategorie ausw&auml;hlen:</label>
    <input type="file" id="files" name="files" multiple="multiple" />
    <input type="hidden" id="MAX_FILE_SIZE" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000" />
    <g:submitButton name="add" class="save button medium" value="Hochladen" />
</g:uploadForm>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The UploadController forwards to the ParserController. This is the ParserController:

```
import org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile

class ParserController {
    def multipartToFileService
    def parserService

    def index() { }

    def takeUploadedFiles() {
       List fileList = request.getFiles('files') // 'files' is the name of the input
       fileList.each { file -> multipartToFileService.convert(file) }

       redirect(action: "parse")
    }

    def parse() {
        parserService.parse()
    }
}
```

So i upload one .html.
At this point i get this exception:

```
2014-06-02 23:04:33,127 [tomcat-http--9] ERROR servlet.GrailsDispatcherServlet  - HandlerInterceptor.afterCompletion threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No value for key [org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl@6398813a] bound to thread [tomcat-http--9]
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:198)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

This exception doesn't stop the application, even the parsing is done perfectly.
But i don't understand this exception, and i found out it might have something to do
with the transactional Services i'm injecting in the PaserController.
Whithout service injection, i don't get the exception (instead i get a MissingPropertyException, of course):

```
import org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile

class ParserController {
//  def multipartToFileService
//  def parserService

    def index() { }

    def takeUploadedFiles() {
    List fileList = request.getFiles('files') // 'files' is the name of the input
        fileList.each { file -> multipartToFileService.convert(file) }

        redirect(action: "parse")
    }

    def parse() {
        parserService.parse()
    }
}
```

Any ideas how to avoid this IllegalStateException?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the problem: https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/2105

- ID: GRAILS-11481
- Description: GrailsDispatcherServlet throws IllegalStateException when using forward() and render()